# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. on data read from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to load data from csv by row, then create 2d array out of each row and store it inside array:

loading:

```
with open('data_more.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

parsing:

```
def getTrainingData():
    label_data = []
    for i in range( 0 , len(data) - 1):
        y = list(data[i][1:41:1])
        y = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda z: int(z),x)),y))
        y = create2Darray(y)
        label_data.append(y)
    labelY = np.array(label_data,dtype=float)
```

create2Darray func:

```
def create2Darray( arr ):
    final_arr = []
    index = 0
    while( index < len(arr)):
        temp = arr[index:index+4:1]
        final_arr.append(temp)
        index+=4
    return final_arr
```

This is simple task, yet i keep recieving erro:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I have read that its related to situation when the shape of elements isnt same. However when i print shape of all elements inside labelY it outputs same shape.

What is causing this problem then? The problem occurs on this line

```
labelY = np.array(label_data,dtype=float)
```

my csv has format

```
number, number, number
```

basicly N numbers in row separated by "," [example](https://pastebin.com/PCe26heH)
thanks for help.

Comment: What does your variable `data` look like?

Comment: Have you tried `np.genfromtxt`?

Comment: my data variable looks like 2D array (atleast after printing )

Comment: what about using `pandas` to read the `csv` and perform operations and then using the `loc` and `iloc` to slice them into `series` that'll directly convert to `np.array`. You can also use the `.dropna()` to drop any value that is `NoneType`

Comment: @iam.Carrot would you mind to put example? I am not very familiar with python. Thanks

Comment: @Darlyn please share a few lines of your `csv` and if possible how does your output `np.array` looks like

Comment: What we need to see is `label_data`, the list that is giving `np.array` problems.

Comment: i will update question of my csv example

Comment: Although I don't understand what you expect, your issue seem to come from the fact that your numbers don't have the same digit length. If you do `y = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda z: int(z),x.zfill(3))),y))`, you can build your array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning:

1. You seem to want to iterate through every line of your file to create an array. The iteration should be over `range(0, len(data))`, not `range(0, len(data) - 1)`: the last element of the range is *exclusive*, so you are currently skipping the last line. In fact, you can write simply `range(len(data))`, or what is even more Pythonic, do

   ```
   for y in data:
       y = y[1:41]
   ```
2. Based on what comes later, you want the 40 elements of `y` starting with the second element. In that case `y[1:41]` is correct (you don't need the trailing `:1`). If you didn't mean to skip the first element, use `y[0:40]`, or more Pythonically `y[:40]`. Remember that the indexing is zero-based and the stop index is *exclusive*.
3. Each element of your `y` list is *not* a number. It is a string, which you read from a file. Normally, you could convert it to a list of numbers using

   ```
   y = [float(x) for x in y]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   y = list(map(float, y))
   ```

   Your code is instead creating a nested list for each element, splitting it by its digits. Is this really what you intend? It certainly does not seem that way from the rest of the question.
4. `create2Darray` seems to expect a list of `4n` numbers, and break it into a 2D list of size `n-by-4`. If you want to keep using pure Python at this point, you can shorten the code using `range`:

   ```
   def create2Darray(arr):
       return [arr[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(arr), 4)]
   ```
5. The result of the 2D operation is appended to a 3D list with `label_data.append(y)`. Currently, because of the digit splitting, `label_data` is a 4D list with a ragged 4th dimension. It is pretty inefficient to append a list that way. You would do much better to have a small function containing the statements in the body of your `for` loop, and use that in a list comprehension.
6. Finally, you convert your 4D array (which should probably be 3D), into a numpy array. This operation fails because your numbers don't all have the same number of digits. Once you fix step #3, the error will go away. There still remains the question of why you want `dtype=np.float` when you explicitly converted everything to an `int`, but that is for you to figure out.
7. Don't forget to add a return value to `getTrainingData`!

**TL;DR**

The simplest thing you can really do though, is to do all the transformations after you convert the file to a 2D numpy array. Your program could be rewritten as

```
with open('data_more.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = [float(x) for x in line[1:] for line in reader]
data = np.array(data).reshape(data.shape[0], -1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a copy-n-paste from your link:

```
In [367]: txt="""frame_video_02_0.jpg,126,37,147,112,100,41,126,116,79,34,96,92,
     ...: 68,31,77,88,1
     ...: """
In [368]: txt=txt.splitlines()
In [369]: data =np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',')
```

`data` is a 2d array of floats:

```
In [370]: data.shape
Out[370]: (3, 401)
In [371]: data[0,:10]
Out[371]: array([ nan, 126.,  37., 147., 112., 100.,  41., 126., 116.,  79.])
```

The first column is `nan`, because it's a text that can't be made into a float.  I could remove it with `data = data[:, 1:]`

I can load the file names separately:

```
In [373]: labels = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', usecols=[0],dtype=None,encoding=None)
In [374]: labels
Out[374]: 
array(['frame_video_02_0.jpg', 'frame_video_02_50.jpg',
       'frame_video_02_100.jpg'], dtype='<U22')
```

I haven't tried debug your code, though with a file like this, reading the numbers into a Python list of lists shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Why not just pass `range(1,41)` to `usecols` the first time around?

Comment: @MadPhysicist.  I'm too lazy to use a complicate `usecols` parameter like that!

Comment: I'm not sure it would even work. Hoping you would test if for me :)

Comment: A range does work - but you have to know ahead of time how many columns there are.

Comment: @hpaulij. OP seems to have a particular number in mind. The 2D convert thing implies that they want a multiple of 4 at all times.