# How to process a sub-process' stdout into a 2d numpy.array

Tags: numpy, subprocess

I'm trying to pipe a subprocess' output (which is a table) using `subprocess.run` with `PIPE` option. I get a raw string, but I cannot map it onto a numpy object. In c++ I'd simply loop over the stream as if it were a file using sscanf, but Python apparently has no such quick import.

I've tried reading about numpy loadtxt, but as far as I can tell it really needs a text file to process, otherwise it does exactly what I need.

Comment: `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) accepts anything that will feed it strings (lines).  For texting answers I often create a list of strings.  For recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635871

Comment: Yes but it requires an actual file, I need something that does it from a string already in memory

Comment: It doesn't require a file.  Look at my example.  If given a string it tries to open a file with that name.  If given something else, such as list of strings, it uses those instead of a file `readline`.

Comment: Ok. Tried that, it worked. So shall you do the honours?